# (web)tools / plugin for Outlook for checking specific words and organize them

Tags: web-apps, outlook, microsoft-exchange

I'm looking for a tool that can help me parse the mass of emails, I have but also organize them in a proper way with flag of different colors or keyword a bit like with gmail.

- Parsing: With keywords like `Name` or locate specific words or `From <Sender>` or `To <recipient>`
- Organisation: With keywords like `Name` or locate specific words or `From <Sender>` or `To <recipient>`

Does something that great, exist?

Thanks

Comment: What criteria are you looking to be able to organise them on? Who from, subject, locate specific words, phrases, date range, some combination of all of them? Please supply some more details.

Comment: Hi @SteveBarnes, please see my update

Answer (score 2):

The majority of what you are looking for are in Outlook itself, just harder to find in the online version.

If you log in and then either select the gear on the top right:
[image]

Then select "Options" then in the new page on the left select "Inbox & Sweep Rules":

[image]

By clicking on the Inbox Rules + symbol:
[image]

Or from the Inbox select the `...` on the top menu, then create rule:

[image]

You can construct rules to filter mails on a combination of Sender, Title, Keyword, etc, and Flag, Move, Forward, etc., e.g.:
[image]

### A couple of caviats:

1. It looks like Inbox rules may not have a run now option like the desktop edition, if you wish to run on existing content you need to use "Sweeps" instead.
2. You can only assign categories or moves to folders if they already exist so you need to do some setup first.